# Java - what replaced Enumeration legacy class

Tags: java, list, arraylist, enumeration

I have the following code:

```
private Map<String, TestInterface> testList = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, testInterface>();

public Enumeration getTestObjects(){
    return testList.elements();
}
```

The code used to use a hashtable, but I have changed it to a hashmap.

My question is, what is the most efficient way to achieve this functionality in java 7, with the hashmap? return a list?

Comment: should i use .values() to return a collection?

Answer (score 2):

Maps can return 3 different collections:

- `keySet()` returns a set containing all the keys (`Set<String>` in your example)
- `values()` returns a Collection containing all the values (`Collection<TestInterface>` in your example)
- `entrySet()` returns a set containing all the entries (`Set<Map.Entry<String, TestInterface>>` in your example)